# Replace single assignment statement with multiple statements with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm struggling with replacing single statement with multiple statements inside the Roslyn code fix provider. When I invoke root.ReplaceNode(assignmentStatement, newStatements)  I always get System.InvalidOperationException 'The item specified is not the element of a list.' I've found that probably the new list of nodes should starts with old one but I want to replace the whole current statement with multiple new statements. How can I accomplish that?

```
private async Task<Document> GenerateCodeFix(Document document, SyntaxToken culprit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var statement = FindAddigmentStatementToReplace(culprit.Parent);
    if (statement == null)
    {
        return document;
    }
    var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);
    var newStatements = GenerateNewStatements()
    var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(assignmentStatement, newStatements)
    return document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ReplaceNode](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Syntax/SyntaxNodeExtensions.cs,38c6f0bbbbf1ba5c,references) overload and pass the statements as an `IEnumerable<SyntaxNode>`. For example:

```
var statement = ( StatementSyntax ) root.FindNode( diagnostic.Location.SourceSpan );
var statements = new SyntaxNode[]
{
    SomeStatement() , 
    SomeStatement()
};

return Task.FromResult( context.Document.WithSyntaxRoot( root.ReplaceNode( statement , statements ) ) );
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing. GenerateNewStatements() returns IEnumerable<SyntaxNode>

Comment: Post the `GenerateNewStatements` code. What statements are you working with?